# Instance of object getting changed in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following global variables.

```
var name1 = "James";
var nameObj = { name: name1 };
```

In button click, I am changing the value in variable name1. While changing the value in name1 instance of the variable is getting changed. Find my code below.

```js
var name1 = "James";
var nameObj = {
  name: name1
};

function point() {
  name1 = "James"
  if (nameObj.name !== name1) {
    alert("instance changed");
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="point()">Click</button>
```

Is there anyway to change the value in name1 without changing its instance?

Comment: Changing the variable doesn't change the object. What are you talking about?

Comment: Try `name1 = "Fred"` and then `console.log(nameObj.name)` and it will log `James`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, because strings are immutable. [Here's a reference from MDN web docs:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#String_type)

> Unlike in languages like C, JavaScript strings are immutable. This means that once a string is created, it is not possible to modify it. However, it is still possible to create another string based on an operation on the original string.

Comment: Use an extra temporary variable to store the original value :)

Comment: What does this have to do with the question? He's not trying to modify a string in place, the question is about the relationship between the variable and the object property.

Comment: I think he's just confused. Maybe he thinks that `==` compares the identity of strings rather than their contents, so he thinks that the assignment `name1 = "James"` should create a new string that is `!= nameObj.name`